# Laravel 4 Use the same Model and Controller for 12 lists for selects

Tags: laravel-4, model, controller

I have to meke models, controllers and views for 12 tables. They have all the same structure id, name, order.

I was thinking and maybe using:

```
Controller 
index($model)
$model::all()
return View::make(all_tables,compact('model'))
edit($model,$id)... and so on.
```

But and don't know if there's a way for using only one model.

Did anybody do anything like this?
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although each model has the same table structure, what you're trying to achieve would not be advisable as you'd lose a lot of the fluent capabilities of [Laravel's Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent).

Regarding the controller, this would work:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class GenericModelController extends Controller
{
    public function loadModelById($model, $id)
    {
        $instance = \App::make('App\\' . ucfirst($model));
        return $instance->find($id);
    }
}
```

You'll need the following route:

```
Route::get('show/{model}/{id}', 'GenericModelController@loadModelById');
```

Example, to load a user with an id of 1:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/show/user/1
```

Edit: I just saw that you're using Laravel 4, so the syntax for defining a route will be a little different I believe but the general concept will still work. Testing in Laravel 5 and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good aproach, but still having to create 12 tables and 12 models. But I will save your anwser, sure I'll have to use it ;)

Comment: Your question says you need to create models for 12 tables, so I assumed the tables already exist. Otherwise, your question probably needs editing to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should get get some idea from here.Please use the link below.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

// app/models/Bear.php

class Bear extends Eloquent {

```
// MASS ASSIGNMENT -------------------------------------------------------
// define which attributes are mass assignable (for security)
// we only want these 3 attributes able to be filled
protected $fillable = array('name', 'type', 'danger_level');

// DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS --------------------------------------------------
// each bear HAS one fish to eat
public function fish() {
    return $this->hasOne('Fish'); // this matches the Eloquent model
}

// each bear climbs many trees
public function trees() {
    return $this->hasMany('Tree');
}

// each bear BELONGS to many picnic
// define our pivot table also
public function picnics() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Picnic', 'bears_picnics', 'bear_id', 'picnic_id');
}
```

}

Comment: This is a simple model-controller, I want to use the same controller and if it's posible the same model for 12 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple way.
Only one model, one controller and one view(index,edit, etc) too.

A single table with
id, name of list, value (name to appears in the list)

Yo pass can pass to de view all the values per list, and for any list in the table you can create de select if it's no empty.